# Where does this "delayed send" capability in Mail come from?

Tags: mail.app

My only plugins as far as I know are Mail Act-On and MailTags. Does this functionality comes from them? I could not find anything on their website. Any other idea?

[image: New message window]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you must be using the Mail Act-On 3 Mavericks beta.

They have a link on their page to it and some what's [new info](http://www.indev.ca/Mavericks.html).

> What is new in Mail Act-On 3
>
> Mavericks Support Mail Act-On 3 now supports OS X 10.8 and 10.9 New
>   interface Reply Templates Composer options including setting delivery
>   times specifying outbox rules to apply specifying archive mailbox for
>   sent mail

Comment: Thanks I had missed it as I was going through their website ! That is a great feature that they should advertise further !